# Can an adjective be converted into a noun by '-s'?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, suffixes

I saw a passage "this doesn't mean to get riches and honors."
'rich' is an adjective but 'riches' is a plural noun according to the dictionary.
Are there any other examples where an adjective becomes a noun by adding suffix '-s' or '-es'? or 'riches' is the only case?

Comment: "riches" is kind of a special case. It was not actually related originally to the plural "-(e)s" suffix of English; it comes from the French word [*richesse*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=riches&allowed_in_frame=0), which has the same suffix historically as [*fortress*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fortress&allowed_in_frame=0). I don't know of any other word with a similar history.

Answer (score 1):

The only ones I can think of are "green" (the color) and "greens" (meaning vegetables), "red" and "reds" (communists) and "blue" and "blues" (feeling sad).

Comment: fast => fasts, good => goods, hopeful => hopefuls, objective => objectives, though these all can be singular.

Comment: @MattSamuel nice!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, yes; good point. You can turn many adjectives into pluralized nouns:

The **yellows** (the team in yellow t-shirts)
The **dispassionates** (phlegmatic people)
Your **smarts** (your know-how)
Hello, my **pretties** (a pimp's greeting, I suppose)
Put your **briefs** in the hamper (underpants)
The **indolents** (the rentier class)

Some you have to do additional work on:

**Fasties**, **wiseguys**, etc.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the usage of "indolents" that supports your meaning?  I couldn't find one --Comrade Timofeev

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Link, what link. I just made it up. I pictured a 1950's electrician servicing apartments on 5th Avenue and wondered what he might call the people constituting the rentier class (currently in hiding - well, at least characters based on them no longer crop up in mass culture), and voila! Word coinage is not against the law. Anyone can do it. When a newly coined word is picked up by a sufficient number of people, links will appear. "Contrapuntal" and "motherfucker", too, were brand-new at some point. My favorite is "metal fatigue," because it means exactly nothing.

Comment: Ok, cool.  The bureau was just checking how others use it because It couldn't find it in any dictionaries.  Carry on, Comrade Ricky.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Jawohl, mein Kommandant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Hillary Clinton quite famously ⁠— or infamously, depending on your political bent ⁠— did so during her run for the office of President of the United States in 2016 when she said:

> "You know, to just be grossly generalistic, you could put half of
>   Trump’s supporters into what I call 'the basket of *[deplorables](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/09/12/opinion/about-the-basket-of-deplorables.html)*.' "

In the above, she used the adjective "deplorable" as a noun for a deplorable person and then pluralized it.  Note that pluralizing it with an "-s" is not required.  She might just as readily have called such a supporter a "deplorable," but then plurality isn't innate to the meaning being conveyed like it is with "riches."

Incidentally, using "deplorables" and using "riches" (were "[riches](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rich?s=t)" not already a plural noun that means the pluralous treasures and caches of money, hence "riches" being plural, associated with wealth - *see def. 3 of 3*) are examples of a type of rhetorical device called a "[metonymy](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/metonymy?s=ts)," meaning not only can you do that, but there's even a word for it.